# getJSON call appears to fire only once?

Tags: jquery, getjson

I have a setintervall which calls (every 10s) the next function:

```
function myJSONCall(imgIDs) {
    var href = $('#href_' + imgIDs[0]).attr('href');
    alert("MyJSONCall..." + href);

    $.getJSON("/mvc-ajax/ac/availability", {
        url: href
    }, function(availability) {
        alert("Availabilit=" + availability);
        if (availability == "OK") {
            alert("It's a valid location");
        } else {
            alert("It's an invalid location");
        }
    });
    alert("I left from myJSONCall");
}
```

I don't know why, the "getJSON" is only triggered one time. The both "alert" set between the $.getJSON are shown every 10s. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

ajax is asynchronous. move your settimeout (or interval) after the ajax call returns:

```
function myJSONCall(imgIDs) {
    var href = $('#href_' + imgIDs[0]).attr('href');
    alert("MyJSONCall..." + href);
    $.getJSON("/mvc-ajax/ac/availability", {
        url: href
    }, function (availability) {
        alert("Availabilit=" + availability);
        if (availability == "OK") {
            alert("It's a valid location");
        } else {
            alert("It's an invalid location");
        }
        setTimeout(myJSONCall, 10000); //SET TIMEOUT HERE
    });
    alert("I left from myJSONCall");
}
```

Comment: @Neal: As suggested I moved the setInterval after the getJSON call, but not successull ! and now the ajax function is only called once.

Comment: do not use `setInterval`. use `setTimeout`

Comment: @Zamboo, that also could mean you are using the wrong function. try using `$.get` instead of `$.getJSON`...

Comment: @Neal : As you set setTimeout in your answer, I copy/past it...I think I Can't use 'get', cause I exchange data using JSON/JACKSON on java server...

Comment: @Neal: I've to check, cause some java code on the other side ... But you're right, with the $.get, it fire every 10 s BUT the setTimeout not fit, I use setInterval. Thanks for your time.